# Do the police need to tell me they are wearing a bodycam or turn it off before they enter my home?

Tags: united-states, privacy, police, recording, private-property

I have an expectation of privacy within my own home, as such It's generally illegal to film me in my home without my knowledge.  I'm wondering how that applies to bodycams on a police officer.  If I invite them into my home do they have to inform me they are wearing a bodycam and it's turned on since they would otherwise be violating my expectation of privacy?

I'd love to know what the precedents are across all of the USA, but since that's probably too much to ask I'll settle for my home state of Maryland.

Comment: That camera's there for your protection. While it's on, officers can't beat the shit out of you for no reason then claim you were "resisting arrest".

Comment: @nick012000 yes it is, and for the police protection if I claim they threatened or extorted me.  This doesn't change my expectation of privacy though.  The fire department is there to protect my safety, that doesn't give them the right to enter my home and test my fire alarm for me without my permission.

Comment: @nick012000 someone might trust a police officer to not abuse their power, and they might value privacy over the protection they see as unnecessary.

Comment: It doesn't answer the legality of the body cams, but [don't step outside your door or let the police in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15uZTcNYMh0) unless they have a warrant. In the former case, you're enabling them to arrest you without investigation and in the latter, you're letting them fish for evidence.

Comment: @nick012000: As I noted above, showing police into your house can be a bad idea since they are then allowed to use "plain sight" evidence against you for unrelated charges. Adding the ability to review footage for if your neighbor left their bong on your end table does not help you.